# Looking for a tool or best practice for centralized mercurial hook management

Tags: mercurial-hook

we have around 50 mercurial repositories, running in a rhodecode instance and i need to maintain their hooks, e.g. to trigger hudson builds.

I'm not very adept with sed/awk etc, so maintaining the hooks is a constant struggle for me. *Most* hooks would be *almost* identical over all repos (just the local repos URL might be different, or i might want temporarily so "switch off" certain hooks for certain repos)

Is there a tool to ease this task? Or maybe a best-practice-setup where those hooks are just "stubs" that invoke a central script where the actual work is happening?

Best Regards

PS: my apologies if this question is already answered, i find it hard to believe that it's not, but i didn't find any answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest ti achieve that is using rcextensions of RhodeCode. You can connect to global post-push hook to trigger hudson builds. This is a global hook that is called for all repositories. This combined with extra_fields functionality of RhodeCode allows you to do customization of certain parameters, or even control